# Android Image Rounded Top

Tags: android

I woudl like to add an image with rounded top corners to my imageView but it doesn't appears rounded.

my shape_round_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<corners android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"/>
</shape>
```

my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_bg">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_round_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />
       </RelativeLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

I set my image programmatically

```
        int id;
        id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("imagename", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        image.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing the correct drawable name `android:background="@drawable/shape_round_top"`or `android:background="@drawable/shape"`?
Except this, everything looks fine

Comment: Yes shape.xml is shape_rounded_top that's correct. It was my fault in this question. I can't find the error.

Comment: I tested your shape_round_top.xml and your imageView in my project, works for me @Fesco

Comment: So what could be my problem is my image to large?

Comment: remove the code image.setImageResource(id); just to test if you can see the imageView since you set the background grey

Comment: Yes i can see the grey shape and it's rounded

Comment: so now we know the problem is caused by the image

Comment: setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageName);

Comment: My images are 231x137 pixels and in png format it seems that my image overrides the background attribute.

Comment: When i set the image -->  
setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageName); i have the same problem

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your problem

Comment: Before: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161019/kaowxkwq.png  And after adding the image http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161019/lh32wu24.png

Comment: try to change a different image for testing, using android:src="drawerable/imageName" for testing

Comment: I change the images in gridviewadapter could it be that my issue depends on my grid item implementation?